# SoundCloud playlist without account

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Is there a way to make a SoundCloud playlist using [their API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/) or some script that will change the embedded players id after the song is done playing? I find it unnecessary to sign up for an account just to make a playlist that I will be changing often. It would be nice not having to sign in every time I want to update or change my playlist. I would rather just change the playlist by entering or changing each songs id. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With normal API this wont work, because you will need at least a clientid to auth against their api. To get that, you need to have a (dev-)account.

But when it comes to their embedded player, afaik you dont need a client id. 
SC created a widget api.

Just check that:

WIDGET API PLAYGROUND > https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

WIDGET DOCS > https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget